# Convert 1D to 2D java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I try to convert 1D to 2D array, but I keep getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and I have tried whatever I could find on the stackoverflow or internet, but I do not understand why I have this issue?

```
public class Arrayto2DArray {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] a = {0,1, 6, 83, 4, 5, 12, 7};
        int[][] b = new int[4][4];

          for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                 b[i][j]=0;
                 System.out.print(b[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
          }   

        System.out.println("--------------------------");


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                try{
                b[i][j] = a[i+j*4];
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(b[i][j]);
            }
                System.out.println();
        }    
    }
}
```

I kind of know why I get this error and it because of this line

```
 b[i][j] = a[i+j*4];
```

but I cannot come up any formula better than this.

Comment: Did you use different code??? When i copied it and tried to run the code from the question, I got a `NullPointerException` from `b[i].length` (first inner for loop). And I even expected this before running the programm btw., because `new int[4][]` creates the same array as the following code: `new int[][] {null, null, null, null}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the second for-loop
Lets say when i = 3 and j= 3
`a[i+j*4]` evaluates to `a[15]` which is out of the array

When you declare you 2-d array, you specified `int[][] b = new int[4][];`, meaning that the first inner for loop  `for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++)` should result in a NullPointerException since `b[i].length` has no predefined length. Before intering the inner for loop, you should define the size of each b[i] like `b[i] = new int[somenumber]`

In regards to convert the 1d loop to a 2d, you need to define the rule around spliting it into the 2-d array. Then accordingly the second for loop need modification

EDIT:You modified your code to have an int[4][4] array, which means you have 16 placeholders. Your 1-d array contain only 8 placeholders. It depends on how you want to sort the array, like it can be

```
b  0   1   2   3
0  0   1   6   83
1  4   5   12  7
2  0   0   0   0
3  0   0   0   0
```

or any other pattern

Assuming the length of 1-d array is 8 and the total index of 2-d array is 16, the following is more of a general solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] a = { 0, 1, 6, 83, 4, 5, 12, 7 };
        int[][] b = new int[4][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                b[i][j] = 0;
                System.out.print(b[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                try {
                    if ((j + i * 4) < a.length)
                        b[i][j] = a[j + i * 4];
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                System.out.print(b[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ya as I said I got it, but how can I have better formula to avoid this issue?

Comment: I notice you updated your question with the known culprit.. You must tell us what is your aim for the second loop

Comment: which second loop? which culprit ?

Comment: how you come up with this? could you show me your source please?

Comment: I am trying to tell you of the difference in the number of index between your 1-d array and 2-d array which is 8 and 16 respectively. You should define how you want to arrange the number in the 2-d array. From that onwards we can work on a general formula. For example, is your size of your 1d array 8 always?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54077/discussion-between-ashish-and-kick-buttowski).

Answer (score 0):

Your correct formula should be like.

```
 int[] a = {0,1, 6, 83, 4, 5, 12, 7};
 int[][] b = new int[4][2];

 int k=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { // Column of 2D array
    for (int j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) { // Row of 2D array
         b[i][j]= a[k++];
         System.out.println(b[i][j]);
    }
 }
```

**Edit:**

For general case, If your row is fixed at 4 but column is not fixed than your 2D conversion formula should be like below.

```
    int col = a.length / 4;
    int remainder = a.length % 4;
    if (remainder > 0) {
        col = col + 1; // Get the correct column size.
    }
    int[][] b = new int[4][col];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (k < a.length) {
               b[i][j] = a[k];
               System.out.println(b[i][j]);
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not 4 by 4? I found this already. it works for what you said but now for my case.

Comment: Your 1D array size is 8, So 4,4 size is redundant, 4,2 size is enough to get all value from array `a[]`.

Comment: what is the general case?

Comment: @KickButtowski, Look at my edit part for general case.

Comment: why four in these lines? int col = a.length / 4;
    int remainder = a.length % 4;

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is your 2D array is a 4*4, so that means for each index, there will be 4 elements i.e. say values. So there would be a total of 16 values, so you would need a 1D array with 16 elements for the above code to work. Right now you have only 8 values in your 1D array.

Comment: So either follow Masud's answer or change your 1D array to have 16 elements i.e. int[] a = {0,1, 6, 83, 4, 5, 12, 7,4, 5, 12, 7,4, 5, 12, 7};

Comment: I did but out put is kind of repeat itself.

Comment: It was an example of how to make a 4X4 2D array work with your code. The array could have any numbers you put in the 1D array. If you want to work with the 1D array that you have got then follow Masud's answer.

Comment: I think i have explained the concept pretty clearly in my answer, you need to understand how arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should change like this

```
public class Arrayto2DArray {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[] a = {0,1, 6, 83, 4, 5, 12, 7};
        int[][] b = new int[4][2];

          for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                 b[i][j]=0;
                 System.out.print(b[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
          }   

        System.out.println("--------------------------");


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                try{

                    b[i][j] = a[i+j*4];
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                System.out.print(b[i][j]+" ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }    
    }
}
```